# How do I use the scalafx KeyCodeCombination.match function?

Tags: scalafx

Here is what I thought would work based on javafx examples I've seen, but I'm getting an error on the (ctlA.match(ke)) pointing to "match" and saying "identifier expected but 'match' found."  Any links to scalafx examples that have complex KeyEvent processing would be appreciated.

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.input.{KeyCode, KeyCombination, KeyCodeCombination, KeyEvent}
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.stage.Stage

object Main extends JFXApp {
  val ctlA = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.A, KeyCombination.ControlDown)
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene {
      onKeyPressed = { ke =>
        if (ctlA.match(ke))
          println("Matches ^A")
        else
          println("No match")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quirky issue. *ScalaFX* is obviously just a wrapper for the *JavaFX API*, and so it tries to faithfully follow that API as well as it can. In this case, there's a slight problem, because `match` is both the name of a function belonging to `KeyCodeCombination` *and* a *Scala* keyword - which is why compilation fails when it reaches this point: the *Scala* compiler thinks this is the `match` keyword, and can't make sense of it.

Fortunately, there is a simple solution: just enclose `match` within backticks, so that your code becomes:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.input.{KeyCode, KeyCombination, KeyCodeCombination, KeyEvent}
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.stage.Stage

object Main extends JFXApp {
  val ctlA = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.A, KeyCombination.ControlDown)
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene {
      onKeyPressed = { ke =>
        if (ctlA.`match`(ke))
          println("Matches ^A")
        else
          println("No match")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your program now runs just fine!

Comment: It does indeed!  Thanks!  From the error message I figured that was the problem but there it was in the API.  I guess I should have poked into the ScalaFX source code, for there it is in back ticks.